# Sending keyboard presses to minimized rdp windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, remote-desktop, voip

Is there a way to send key presses to a minimized rdp window?

For example:  If I was rdping to another computer that had a voip program that uses a push-to-talk key (for example, mumble) is there any way to have the rdp window minimized but then send the push-to-talk key through?  My mouse has extra buttons that can be bound to different keys.  The goal is to make it so that when I press them, it would be sent through to the voip program on the other computer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge that would have to be something done from the RDP application level. Without focus to the RDP window and the lack of a global keyboard hook from the RDP application, there is no way to do this other than passing messages directly to the process which is messy and not insured to work.

In general, windows considers a window "minimized" and out of focus and therefore non targetable until focus is returned or the window is restored.